# Month in MM using Month() in Hive

Tags: date, hive, hiveql, monthcalendar

```
Select * from concat(YEAR(DATE_SUB(MAX(Column_name),60),MONTH(DATE_SUB(MAX(Column_name),60),-01)
```

The `month()` yields only **single** digit for months until September i.e Jan returns `1` instead of `01`. Need help in handling this.

I am using this output to feed to another `SELECT` query using `TO_DATE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`month()` function returns integer, that is why there is no leading zero. You can use `lpad(month,2,0)` function to format month:

```
hive> select lpad(month('2017-09-01'),2,0);
OK
09
Time taken: 0.124 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select lpad(month('2017-10-01'),2,0);
OK
10
Time taken: 0.433 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Alternatively you can use `substr()` to extract year and month from the date:

```
hive> select substr('2017-10-01',1,4) as year, substr('2017-10-01',6,2) as month;
OK
year    month
2017    10
```

date_sub() function prior to Hive 2.1.0 (HIVE-13248) return type was a String because no Date type existed when the method was created. See here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF