# How to partition a table by month and day in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-partitions

I have created a table with:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE extab (
vendorID string, 
orderID string , 
ordertime string
) 
location '/common_folder/data'
```

Then I created a partition by month and day

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE part_extab(
endorID string, 
orderID string , 
ordertime string
) 
PARTITIONED by (month string, day string)
location '/common_folder/data'
```

Then insert data into the partitioned table

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE 
select vendorId, orderId, ordertime , month, day
FROM extab
```

HOW do I extract month , day from ordertime ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic partition load. If your date in correct format, `month()` and `day()` functions will work:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE part_extab partiion (month, day)
select vendorId, orderId, ordertime , 
       lpad(month(ordertime),2,0) as month,  
       lpad(day(ordertime),2,0) as day
FROM extab;
```

Alternatively you can use substr() for extract month and day, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46661170/2700344) answer